# How to open an app in terminal and passing the current working directory?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, terminal, textmate

I often want to open the entire directory I'm working in by using the `mate` command, but how do I pass in the working directory itself?

For example, if I'm working in a rails app and I want to open the app folder into the TextMate tree, I would do `mate app`, but how could I pass in the working directory itself (i.e. open the entire rails app in the tree)?

Comment: So you want the TextMate Project window to expand the contents of the app folder?

Comment: Nope I just want to open the current working directory straight into textmate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mate .` will open the currently directory. I use the `.` directory a lot, for example open finder for the current directory `open .`.

Answer (score 58):

The command you might be looking for is

```
pwd
```

Comment: This will not work if the cwd is not the same directory where the script lays down.

Answer (score 36):

```
# Assign the current work directory to the bash script variable 'CWD'.
CWD=$(pwd)

# Print it.
printf "%s\n" ${CWD}
```

Answer (score 4):

Getting the current directory is as simple as typing `pwd`, or `echo $PWD`.

Now, if you want to open TextMate in a particular directory, you can do:

```
(cd /target/directory && mate)
```

Comment: you don't need brackets for it.

Answer (score 4):

```
mate `pwd`/yourfile

mate `pwd`/app
```

Or you can using `mate $PWD/app`

Comment: (comment deleted, I see what the author was asking now)

Answer (score 1):

```
DIR=$(readlink -f $0);
IFS='/' read -a array <<< "$DIR";
apath=("${array[@]:0:${#array[@]}-1}");
rpath=$(IFS=/ ; echo "${apath[*]}");
cd $rpath
```

Answer (score 1):

The current working directory as set by the cd command is available in shell variable `PWD`, e.g.

```
echo $PWD
```