# How to join paths in shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

To get a file in my `cwd` in python I can do:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()

filename = 'file.txt'
path = os.path.join(cwd, filename)
```

How would I do the same in a shell script?

Comment: Also how to [get your working directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635456/how-do-you-get-the-current-working-directory-in-bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current working directory can be obtained in bash with the command `pwd`.
Usually, the variable `$PWD` contains the directory. So something like that should do:

```
full_path="${PWD}/foo.txt"
```

and by calling the `pwd` command:

```
full_path="$(pwd)/foo.txt"
```